# Go back button to load related html from javascript template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I'm using JavaScript templating for my application, something similar to this:

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/template">
    <!-- Template here -->
</script>
```

Where contents of each such template are loaded into `#container` div based on what action users perform.

Issue with this is that it all happens on same page, thus when users click back and forward buttons in the browser they will go to previous webpage they were on instead to related screen in my application. Is there a way say if I add `#my-template-id` string to my url when the template is loaded or something to know what page to go to / what template to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just set `window.location.hash` with the hash you want to add (exclude the #). To see what the current hash is just use the `window.location.hash` string (see example below). Listening into hash changes can be done too if you want to change the view based on the hash. For this use the `onhashchange` listener. Note that when you change the hash via `window.location.hash` it fires onhashchange. Using a flag will avoid confusion, e.g.

```
//making hash change
imChangingHash = true;
window.location.hash = 'thisPage';

$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
    if(imChangingHash) {
       imChangingHash = false;
       return;
    }

    //this is now a back/forward button hash change
    console.log('back - forward button moved page to: ' + window.location.hash);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at [history js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to use some kind of router in your application which will take care of the fragment for you.

Here are 2 examples used in fullstack frameworks :

- [Routing in Ember](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/)
- [Routing in Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)